# Bootstrap buttons group not displayed properly in footer of a panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and can't find my problem where button groups in not aligned properly when inserten in right hand side of the panel footer.

My code id:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading"><b>My Title</b><span class="pull-right">123</span></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Just a test text<br>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    Some information herre

                    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Group of buttons <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> PDF</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->
```

To demonstrate a problem please take a look at working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/69r7s63w/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the easiest and cleanest way is to add a `clearfix` class to your footer:

```
<div class="panel-footer clearfix">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r819f85u/

You don't need to add any extra markup to archive this. If you have multiple instances like this, you can even override `panel-footer` to let take effect automatically, but you'd better use Less/Sass/... version, otherwise will be complicated to add an `clearfix` effect.

Below is an example by using Sass:

```
// Overriding must be written or imported after Bootstrap
.panel-footer {
  @include clearfix;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for me and is easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust line height of text Some information here, since it is not wrapped under any div or so..

Just change

`Some information here` to `<span class="footer-text">Some information here</span>` and then adjust the line height of `.footer-text` class using following CSS

```
.footer-text{
   line-height:33px;
}
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/69r7s63w/1/

**Updated Solution with best practices**

Change HTML to this :

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-6 footer-text">Some information herre</div>
        <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
                Group of buttons <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> PDF</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/69r7s63w/3/

Comment: This is not a recommended way, you have to add extra markup and styles.

Comment: I am just trying to run your code from iPad and the problem is still visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use containers it will fit better within the footer.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p>
            Some information herre
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">Group of buttons <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> PDF</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69r7s63w/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the size of the button to `btn-sm or btn-xs`.  Also I'm not entirely sure why but making the button float right causes it to not be able to stretch heights within a container, usually I see

`<div class="clearfix"></div>`

put at the end of float elements which will stretch the container.

Comment: Thank you - this solution works ok, however I would agree with nightire that his solution is cleaner for my code.